# Determine which version of linux/unix/darwin I have

Tags: centos

I have root ssh/terminal access to a linux server.   How do I determine which version of centos I have?

Some people suggested I run the command `cat /etc/redhat-release` but I got an error saying file not found.

**In fact, i'm not entirely sure i'm even using CentOS.**  That's what some suggested it might be.

Here's a list of commands I tried that gave me no file or directory error:

```
cat /etc/*release*
cat /etc/*version*
cat /proc/*version*
cat /proc/*release*
```

Here's a list of linux commands that do not exist:

```
lsb_release: command not found
wget: command not found
yum: command not found
```

Comment: @panaroik  - that also gave me a no file in directory

Comment: John sorry, just moved my comment to answer :)

Comment: `cat /proc/version`?

Comment: What's the output of `uname -a`?  Many distros put their own mark in the kernel version number.  RHEL-derived kernel versions tend to have the string "EL" or "el" in them.  At least this can help you figure out *if* you're running RHEL or a derivitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one to match all possibilities if there is some similar file by any chance

```
cat /etc/*release*
cat /etc/*version*
```

Comment: both says no such file in directory

Comment: just checking, is your OS linux or unix?
uname -a ?

Comment: AH! got it.  uname -a says this is Darwin.  Ok so it's not cent os at all!

Comment: @John more generally, it's not even linux.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
cat /etc/issue
```

Comment: It says no such file in directory

Comment: `lsb_release -a`?

Comment: lsb_release command not found

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
# rpm -qa | grep release
centos-release-5-8.el5.centos
centos-release-notes-5.8-0
```

...although the fact that you don't have /etc/redhat-release implies you either don't have a redhat variant, or that the installed instance has been seriously modified.

Answer (score 0):

If it's Darwin, does `sw_vers` give you anything useful?

Something like:

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.8.1
BuildVersion:   12B19
```